# How can I merge a list with multiple items into 1 list? (Apple Script)

Tags: applescript

After getting the data from a .plist file I have a multi-item list of all the arrays contained in the .plist file. How can I merge them into 1 list?

thanks,

```
type on getData()
    tell application "System Events"
        set thePropertyListFilePath to FilePad
        tell property list file thePropertyListFilePath
            try
                return value of every property list item
            on error errMsg
                display dialog "ERROR: " & errMsg
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end getData

set allData to getData()
```

As an example, I get the following result:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, "a", "b"}, {5, 6, 7}, {"c", "d", 8, 9}}
```

What is the simplest way to get the desired result below?

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, "a", "b", 5, 6, 7, "c", "d", 8, 9}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a smart way with help of the Foundation framework and the `unionOfArrays` key path of `NSArray`

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set nestedList to {{1, 2, 3, 4, "a", "b"}, {5, 6, 7}, {"c", "d", 8, 9}}
set flattened to ((current application's NSArray's arrayWithArray:nestedList)'s valueForKeyPath:"@unionOfArrays.self") as list
```

Comment: That works fine for my situation, thanks for the quick response!